# How can I include Strings data on x axis of vico chart line chart

Tags: kotlin, charts

I am using [vicocharts](https://github.com/patrykandpatrick/vico/tree/master) library to plot graphs in a Kotlin Jetpack compose material3 android app. Below is an example of how I am creating linecharts with x - axis and y - axis values as floats. How can I create a linechart in cases where x - axis values are strings. For example, how would I create a linechart that shows sales figures by day of the week so that on the x - axis we have days of the week (Mon, Tue, Wed ...) while the y - axis holds the sales amounts? I can't figure out how to achieve this. Here is a link to the [vicocharts](https://github.com/patrykandpatrick/vico/tree/master) repository.

I would also appreciate suggestions of other charting libraries that might be easier to use.

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Brush
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.toArgb
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.alele.practicevico.ui.theme.PracticeVicoTheme
import com.patrykandpatrick.vico.compose.axis.horizontal.rememberBottomAxis
import com.patrykandpatrick.vico.compose.axis.vertical.rememberStartAxis
import com.patrykandpatrick.vico.compose.chart.Chart
import com.patrykandpatrick.vico.compose.chart.line.lineChart
import com.patrykandpatrick.vico.compose.component.shape.shader.fromBrush
import com.patrykandpatrick.vico.core.axis.AxisItemPlacer
import com.patrykandpatrick.vico.core.component.shape.shader.DynamicShaders
import com.patrykandpatrick.vico.core.entry.FloatEntry
import com.patrykandpatrick.vico.core.entry.entryModelOf
import com.patrykandpatrick.vico.core.entry.entryOf
import kotlin.random.Random

@Composable
fun LineChart (
    data: List<FloatEntry>
) {


    val chartEntryModel = entryModelOf(data)

    Chart(
        chart = lineChart(
            spacing = 4.dp,
            lines = listOf(
                com.patrykandpatrick.vico.core.chart.line.LineChart.LineSpec(
                    lineThicknessDp = 0.5f,
                    lineColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.tertiary.toArgb(),
                    lineBackgroundShader = DynamicShaders.fromBrush(
                        brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
                            listOf(
                                MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceTint.copy(com.patrykandpatrick.vico.core.DefaultAlpha.LINE_BACKGROUND_SHADER_START),
                                MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceTint.copy(com.patrykandpatrick.vico.core.DefaultAlpha.LINE_BACKGROUND_SHADER_END)
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
        ),
        model = chartEntryModel,
        startAxis = rememberStartAxis(
            itemPlacer = AxisItemPlacer.Vertical.default(maxItemCount = 5),
            guideline = null
        ),
        bottomAxis = rememberBottomAxis(
            itemPlacer = AxisItemPlacer.Horizontal.default(
                spacing = data.size/5,
                offset = 10,
                shiftExtremeTicks = false
            ),
            guideline = null,
            tickLength = 0.dp,
        ),
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(300.dp)
    )
}

val data1 = List(200) { entryOf(it , Random.nextFloat()*10) }

val data2 = listOf(
    FloatEntry(1F, 2F),
    FloatEntry(2F, 3F),
    FloatEntry(3F, 3F),
    FloatEntry(4F, 0F), 
    FloatEntry(5F, 1F),
    FloatEntry(6F, 0F),
    FloatEntry(7F, 10F),
    FloatEntry(8F, 0F),
    FloatEntry(9F, 0F), 
    FloatEntry(10F, 0F), 
    FloatEntry(11F, 0F),
    FloatEntry(12F, 5F), 
)
```

Answer (score 3):

It would help if you tried to add the *valueFormatter* parameter to *rememberBottomAxis* function. For example:

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Brush
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.toArgb
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.alele.practicevico.ui.theme.PracticeVicoTheme
import com.patrykandpatrick.vico.compose.axis.horizontal.rememberBottomAxis
import com.patrykandpatrick.vico.compose.axis.vertical.rememberStartAxis
import com.patrykandpatrick.vico.compose.chart.Chart
import com.patrykandpatrick.vico.compose.chart.line.lineChart
import com.patrykandpatrick.vico.compose.component.shape.shader.fromBrush
import com.patrykandpatrick.vico.core.axis.AxisItemPlacer
import com.patrykandpatrick.vico.core.axis.AxisPosition
import com.patrykandpatrick.vico.core.axis.formatter.AxisValueFormatter
import com.patrykandpatrick.vico.core.component.shape.shader.DynamicShaders
import com.patrykandpatrick.vico.core.entry.FloatEntry
import com.patrykandpatrick.vico.core.entry.entryModelOf
import com.patrykandpatrick.vico.core.entry.entryOf
import kotlin.random.Random

private val daysOfWeek = listOf("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun")
private val bottomAxisValueFormatter =
    AxisValueFormatter<AxisPosition.Horizontal.Bottom> { x, _ -> daysOfWeek[x.toInt() % daysOfWeek.size] }

@Composable
fun LineChart(
    data: List<FloatEntry>
) {
    
    val chartEntryModel = entryModelOf(data)

    Chart(
        chart = lineChart(
            spacing = 4.dp,
            lines = listOf(
                com.patrykandpatrick.vico.core.chart.line.LineChart.LineSpec(
                    lineThicknessDp = 0.5f,
                    lineColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.tertiary.toArgb(),
                    lineBackgroundShader = DynamicShaders.fromBrush(
                        brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
                            listOf(
                                MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceTint.copy(com.patrykandpatrick.vico.core.DefaultAlpha.LINE_BACKGROUND_SHADER_START),
                                MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceTint.copy(com.patrykandpatrick.vico.core.DefaultAlpha.LINE_BACKGROUND_SHADER_END)
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
        ),
        model = chartEntryModel,
        startAxis = rememberStartAxis(
            itemPlacer = AxisItemPlacer.Vertical.default(maxItemCount = 5),
            guideline = null
        ),
        bottomAxis = rememberBottomAxis(
            valueFormatter = bottomAxisValueFormatter,
            itemPlacer = AxisItemPlacer.Horizontal.default(
                spacing = data.size / 5,
                offset = 10,
                shiftExtremeTicks = false
            ),
            guideline = null,
            tickLength = 0.dp,
        ),
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(300.dp)
    )
}

val data1 = List(200) { entryOf(it, Random.nextFloat() * 10) }

val data2 = listOf(
    FloatEntry(1F, 2F),
    FloatEntry(2F, 3F),
    FloatEntry(3F, 3F),
    FloatEntry(4F, 0F),
    FloatEntry(5F, 1F),
    FloatEntry(6F, 0F),
    FloatEntry(7F, 10F),
    FloatEntry(8F, 0F),
    FloatEntry(9F, 0F),
    FloatEntry(10F, 0F),
    FloatEntry(11F, 0F),
    FloatEntry(12F, 5F),
)
```